# How do I debug AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'match'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have created a flask application with flask-wtforms which crashes after hitting submit on the form.

The error seems to happen in the [Flask-WTF function](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.validate_on_submit) `validate_on_submit` and tells me that a list object I am passing does not contain the match attribute.

Right now I assume it must be something simple like me wrongly defining the Fields in the FormVendor class, but I am not sure what the issue really is.

**Stacktrace**

```
  File ".../webshop/vendor.py", line 38, in vendorsignup_post
    if form.validate_on_submit():

...
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'match'
...

  File ".../webshop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/validators.py", line 286, in __call__
    match = self.regex.match(field.data or '')
```

My code:

**vendor.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, FileField, HiddenField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, NumberRange, Regexp, InputRequired, AnyOf

vendor = Blueprint('vendor', __name__)

class FormVendor(FlaskForm):
    per_email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired(),Email(message="wrong mail")])
    per_first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    per_last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    adr_city = StringField('City', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    adr_state = StringField('State', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    adr_country = StringField('Country', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    adr_line1 = StringField('Address Line 1', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    adr_line2 = IntegerField('Address Line 2', validators=[DataRequired()])
    adr_postal_code = IntegerField('Postal Code', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired(),Regexp(['([1-468][0-9]|[57][0-7]|9[0-6])[0-9]{2}'])])
    dob_day = IntegerField('Date of Birth: Day', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    dob_month = IntegerField('Date of Birth: Month', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    dob_year = IntegerField('Date of Birth: Year', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    fin_account_number = StringField('IBAN Account Number', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    id_front = FileField('ID Front', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    id_back = FileField('ID Back', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    address_front = FileField('Address Document', validators=[DataRequired(), InputRequired()])
    accept_tos = BooleanField('I accept the TOS', validators=[DataRequired()])

@vendor.route('/vendorsignup')
@login_required
def vendorsignup():
    form = FormVendor()
    return render_template('vendorsignup.html', user=current_user, form=form)

@vendor.route('/vendorsignup', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def vendorsignup_post():
    form = FormVendor()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Successfully registered as vendor")
        return redirect(url_for('main.sell'))
    print(form.errors)
    return render_template('vendorsignup.html', form=form)
```

**vendorsignup.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
{% endif %}
<form method="POST" action="/vendorsignup" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="mb-3">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.per_email.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.per_email(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.per_first_name.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.per_first_name(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.per_last_name.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.per_last_name(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.adr_city.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.adr_city(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.adr_state.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.adr_state(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.adr_country.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.adr_country(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.adr_line1.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.adr_line1(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.adr_line2.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.adr_line2(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.adr_postal_code.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.adr_postal_code(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.dob_day.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.dob_day(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.dob_month.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.dob_month(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.dob_year.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.dob_year(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.fin_account_number.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.fin_account_number(size=20,class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.id_front.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.id_front(class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.id_back.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.id_back(class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.address_front.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.address_front(class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.accept_tos.label(class='form-label') }}
    {{ form.accept_tos(class="form-control") }}
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `adr_postal_code` IntegerField, your last validator looks like this:

```
Regexp(['([1-468][0-9]|[57][0-7]|9[0-6])[0-9]{2}'])
```

If you take a look at the the [`Regexp.__init__` source code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/validators.py#L344), you can see that it expects the `regex` parameter to be a string or regular expression object, but you're passing in a list containing a single string.

Here's what the `__init__` looks like:

```
def __init__(self, regex, flags=0, message=None):
    if isinstance(regex, str):
        regex = re.compile(regex, flags)
    self.regex = regex
    self.message = message
```

And then, just below the `__init__`, you'll find the `__call__` method, which is where your code fails. `__call__` assumes that whatever type `self.regex` is, it must have a `match` method. Since you passed in a list, `self.regex` will be a list, and has no `match` method.

So, your validator should instead be:

```
Regexp('([1-468][0-9]|[57][0-7]|9[0-6])[0-9]{2}')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the in-depth explanation of why this is happening  Correcting the error gives me a new error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" Tinkering around with Regexp seems to show me that I must be somehow doing something wrong with how I am using the Regexp?

Comment: @RoderickJonsson I don't know anything about wtforms. Which line specifically is throwing the exception? Maybe edit your question and include the new traceback. Let me know once you've edited your question so that I get a notification.